# How to inject mock into Grails plugin?

Tags: grails, testing, groovy, mocking

**Please note:** Although this question *mentions* RabbitMQ its really a core Grails/testing question at heart.

I'm interested in using the [Grails RabbitMQ plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/rabbitmq) so that my Grails app can pub/sub messages.

For testing purposes, I'd like to stub/mock a message broker so that I don't actually have to spin up a full-blown RabbitMQ broker to run some automated tests, and to see if my app handles the publishing and consuming of messages correctly.

For the subscribing-side of things, I'm interested in a `QueueConsumer` object which is ultimately obtained from a `ConnectionFactory` instance [as this example shows](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html):

> ConnectionFactory >> Connection >> Channel >> QueueConsumer

The good news is: to configure the RabbitMQ plugin you just need to configure a `ConnectionFactory` in your `Config.groovy`:

```
rabbitmq {
    connectionfactory {
        username = 'guest'
        password = 'guest'
        hostname = 'localhost'
    }
}
```

Not sure if I can leverage this somehow but wanted to point it out.

So my thinking is to use something like Mockito to mock a `QueueConsumer` instance (whose `nextDelivery()` method gives me a mock `Delivery` instance with desired test behavior) and inject that mock factory into my plugin somehow.

Let's pretend that the mock might look like this (in a test case):

```
@Test
def onConsumeDoSomething() {
    // Given
    QueueConsumer mockConsumer = Mockito.mock(QueueConsumer.class)
    Delivery mockDelivery = Mockito.mock(Delivery.class)

    mockDelivery.when(getBody()).thenReturn("<message>test message</message>")
    mockConsumer.when(nextDelivery()).thenReturn(mockDelivery)

    // TODO: How to inject 'mockConsumer' into Grails for a test?

    // When
    // TODO: How to exercise the test?

    // Then
}
```

My question is: how could I do this, and what might a test for it look like? **I'm more interested in an *integration test* using the mock than in a unit test like the one above.** So, something where I could do a `grails test-app` or even `run-app` and the mock gets injected.